# Migrate kafka client to latest version

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to migrate old Java code which uses `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.0.1-mapr-1803` but I get missing Java methods:

```
public Producer kafkaProducer() {
    final Properties producerproperties = new Properties();
    producerproperties.put(ProducerConfig.STREAMS_BUFFER_TIME_CONFIG,
        kafkaProducerConfiguration.getBufferTimeInMilliSeconds());
    producerproperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        kafkaProducerConfiguration.getProducerBootstrapServers());
    return new Producer<String, String>(producerproperties);
  }
```

`STREAMS_BUFFER_TIME_CONFIG` ("streams.buffer.max.time.ms") is missing.

```
private void setHeaders(SimpleMapMessage message, ConsumerRecord<K, V> record) {
    message.setHeader("partition", String.valueOf(record.partition()));
    message.setHeader("producer", record.producer());
  }
```

`producer()` is missing.

Do you know how I have to replace `producer()` into the latest kafka client?

Test project: https://github.com/rcbandit111/kafka_streams_migration_poc/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/portal/account/platform/kafka/consumer/EventConsumer.java

Change `implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.1.1-mapr-1808-streams-6.1.0'` to `implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.7.0'` to get the exception.

Comment: can you share the pom too ? actually a small reproducer would help everyone more.

Comment: I added a test project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it able to be compiled:

1. You could simply add `"streams.buffer.max.time.ms"` as String instead of a constant:

```
producerproperties.put("streams.buffer.max.time.ms", kafkaProducerConfiguration.getBufferTimeInMilliSeconds());
```

(if this should still be a valid config, which I doubt, it will be recognized as property)

2. Not sure what `record.producer()` was supposed to achieve, it's also just a String. You could put an empty String there or extract a specific Header that you are sure exists.

However mind there is no guarantee that your code behaves the way you expect when making this large of a jump in versions (also coming from a more specific release). I'd recommend performing unit tests and/or redefining what you actually try to achieve with the code, restructuring the application with current methods and interfaces.